# Android kotlin Object Any type mismatch

Tags: java, android, kotlin, type-mismatch

How to assign kotlin map to java library map.
This gives type mismatch error for Object and Any.

I need to assign java map variable in a 3rd party java library, from my kotlin code map.

```
val model = JavaModel() //from 3rd party java library

val params:MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
params.put("key","value")
model.params = params //gives error below
```

Type mismatch: inferred type is `MutableMap<String, Any>` but `Map<String, Object>?` was expected

Comment: post your code.

Comment: What is "java library map"? Where is your code?

Comment: Show the code for your `JavaModel` class, in particular the `params` field declaration.

Comment: İt is compiled code I am not able to see it. Only thing that I can say is JavaModel.params is Map<String, Object>

Comment: I try to reproduce problem using Java 11, Kotlin 1.6.10 but it can compile and run without any problem. I think that Kotlin already supported this type conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Java's `Object` is not the same as Kotlin's `Any`, so the type `MutableMap<String, Any>` and `Map<String, Object>?` mismatched, because you cannot change the 3rd party java library, just declare the `params` as:

```
val params: MutableMap<String, Object> = HashMap()
```

Comment: Kotlin will show Type mismatch for such code:
    `var param: MutableMap<String, Object?> = hashMapOf(); param.put("key", "")`

Comment: Your are right 3mpty, so what is the solution? Both solution gives exact same error.

Comment: Seems right, @DiRiNoiD you should share more info about your `JavaModel`

Answer (score 0):

`JavaModel.params`requires explicitly `<String, Object>`. You cannot use Kotlin `Any` there. Also `HashMap` in Kotlin is mapped type so your best shot is to do simple workaround:

Extend HashMap from java, ex. `ParamsMap.java`:

```
public class ParamsMap extends HashMap<String, Object> { }
```

And use it like this:

```
val model = JavaModel()

val params = ParamsMap()
params.put("key","value")
model.params = params
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can achieve this is to create a new Java class and do the operation inside it. I give the params Java Map as parameter and and I made the operation inside the Java class.

Kotlin automatically behaves any Object as Any so it gives type mismatch for the assignment.

```
public class ObjectMapper {
    public static void setParam(Map<String, Object> params, String key, String value) {
        params.put(key, value);
    }
}
```